# Create multiple record in a single submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model, submit

I'm pretty new to MVC 3 so I don't know if this is possible. If it isn't, what would be the best approach:

I have a Model1 with a lot of properties and a create view. In this page, people fill the needed data and do submit. But my problem is that the Model1 also contains SubModel1, which is another model (and another table in the database). I would want to offer buttons on the create page to create "on the fly" some SubModel1 via a pop-up CSS form and when the SubModel1 is submited, update the Model1 create page with a list of SubModel1 but :

1. Since the Model1 is not currently saved, where would I save the Submodel when the Submit is done on the CSS pop-up form? Can I just add it to the Model1 model? If so, how?
2. When I go back to the Create page, what to I need to do so it update and show the SubModel1 Names for example in a list.
3. When I will do submit on the Model1, do I only need to save the Model1 and the rest will automatically save or do I need to do all the saving in the correct order myself in the controller?

Sorry if it's newb question but it will help me a lot!
Thanks!

Comment: couple of questions are both model already physicaly exists, is your problem that you want to present two models on one view and based on submodel get the model data

Comment: If by physically exist you mean "on the database", no they doesn't. It's a create view. So my goal would be that at the end the user click on submit and both the Model1 and all of it SubModel1 gets created but I don't know how to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like a lot of people say, there is no stupid question.

The problem you expose here is something that happens a lot and the solution is sometime simpler than we think.

There is more than one way to actually achieve what you want to do, but in my opinion, for a smoother experience, using JavaScript to display the PopUp and add the sub-item to the Model1 is the best option.

Your SubModel1 items should not be saved right away in your database for the simple reason that your Model1 might not be submited.

In this case your CSS popup should only really be a form (div or whatever) that exists in the page and use javascript to add a new row to the Model1 item.

Thus, when you submit the Model1 it will contain all the modifications, including the new SubModel1 items.

[There is a naming convention to using to allow proper serialization of the form when submitting.](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

By sticking to this binding, this will allow you to wait for your Model1 in your controler.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPostAction(Model1 item)
{
  //do some verification here
  if ( ModelState.IsValid )
  {
    //save your Model1 data
    foreach( SubModel1 subitem in item.SubItems )
    {
      //Save your SubItems here
    }
  }
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

How you save your items and sub items is depedant on how you access your data ( Entity Framework, linq-to-sql, classic ADO.NET or whatever suits your needs)

***More Details : Some exemple on how to add the new elements***

This is the kind of javascript that you will need to add the element (here I used a table to display the subitems)

For this example, the SubItems array is name like this :

```
SubItems[0-based index].{SubItem property name}
```

Thus I know that when I add a new Item, the new names will be :

```
SubItems[SubItems.length].name
SubItems[SubItems.lenght].description
```

Once you submit, the server will bind the names to the properties in your Model.

You can see this in action on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mj7kg/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TestButton").click(function () {
        var $parent = $("#SubItems");
        var $newItem = $parent.find("tr:last").clone();

        $parent = $parent.find("tr:last").parent();
        var numElem = $parent.find("tr").length;

        $newItem.find('[name$="description"]').attr("name", "SubItems[" + numElem + "].description");
        $newItem.find('[name$="name"]').attr("name", "SubItems[" + numElem + "].name");

        $parent.append($newItem);
    });
});
```

Comment: This confirms a lot of things... Let's see if I can program it! I'll mark you as the answer if it works :) Thanks

Comment: Can you add an example how to add SubModel1 to the current Model1? I'm a little bit confuse on how to do this.

Comment: I added some details. I used super simple models to make it easy to read, but this works no matter how complex you objects are.

Comment: Oufff... I never though that the code for this would be in jquery so I'm a little lost. I will need some time to figure it out and try it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That is one way of doing it. There is other options that doesn't include javascript, but then you have to store the information in SessionState to have it available when you get back to your controler.

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me. It work like a charm and it's so easy :) Have a good day!